# How to add X spinner type hamburger menu

Tags: html, jquery, css

Hey all  have this menu which i wish to have toggle on click X and again back to hamburger style.

could someone help me out here? I just have no clue how that is achieved. sharing my menu codes here. hope some expert could help me out.

here are my menu codes

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
 $('#menulink').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  if($('.navigation-wrapper').hasClass('show-menu')) {
   $('.navigation-wrapper').removeClass('show-menu');
   $('.navigation').hide();
   $('.navigation li').removeClass('small-padding');
  } else {
   $('.navigation-wrapper').addClass('show-menu');
   $('.navigation').fadeIn();
   $('.navigation li').addClass('small-padding');
    }
 });
  
});
```

```css
.hamburger-wrapper {
 padding: 0;
 background: #000;
 position: fixed;
 top: 40px;
 left:90px;
 width: 50px;
 z-index: 999;
}

.inner-hamburger-wrapper {
 background: #ca1404;
 width: 100%;
 padding: 8px 0;
}

.hamburger {
 width: 50%;
 height: 3px;
 margin: 4px auto;
 background: #fff;
 border-radius: 2px;
}

.menu-title {
 position: absolute;
 top: 10px;
 right: 0;
 width: 50%;
}

.menu-title p {
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 18px;
 line-height: 22px;
 text-align: center;
}

.navigation-wrapper {
 background: linear-gradient(180deg, #C7100C 0%, #3F5EFB 100%);
 padding: 40px 0 0 0;
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 z-index: 900;
 display: none;
}

.navigation {
 padding: 50px 5% 0 5%;
 display: none;
}

.show-menu {
 display: block;
}

.navigation li {
 list-style: none;
 margin: 50px 0;
 transition: all ease .6s;
} .navigation li.small-padding {
 margin: 0;
  }

.navigation li a {
 display: block;
 padding: 10px 0 10px 1%;
 color: #fff !important;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-size: 150%;
 letter-spacing: .1em;
 border-left: 3px solid #000;
 -moz-transition: all ease .3s;
 -webkit-transition: all ease .3s;
 -ms-transition: all ease .3s;
 -o-transition: all ease .3s;
 transition: all ease .3s;
}

.navigation li a:hover {
 color: #fff;
 padding-left: 2%;
 border-left: 3px solid #eee;
}

@media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 768px) {
.hamburger-wrapper {
 padding: 0;
 background: #000;
 position: fixed;
 top: 30px;
 left:5px;
 width: 50px;
 z-index: 999;
}

.navigation li a {
 display: block;
 padding: 10px 0 10px 1%;
 color: #bbb;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-size: 90%;
 letter-spacing: .1em;
 border-left: 3px solid #000;
 -moz-transition: all ease .3s;
 -webkit-transition: all ease .3s;
 -ms-transition: all ease .3s;
 -o-transition: all ease .3s;
 transition: all ease .3s;
 border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 
}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="menulink" href="#">
 <div class="hamburger-wrapper">
  <div class="inner-hamburger-wrapper">
   <div class="hamburger"></div>
   <div class="hamburger"></div>
   <div class="hamburger"></div>
  </div>
 </div>
</a>

<div class="navigation-wrapper">

 <ul class="navigation">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Website Design</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Search Engine Optimization</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">User Experience</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">AB Testing</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
</div>
```

would appreciate your kind help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You should do the following things:

1. add a class like 'active' to the hamburger button when active (Jquery > toggleClass)
2. the three lines in the button can be animated seperately by making classes for each of them : #menulink.active .hamburger-wrapper .inner-hamburger-wrapper div:nth-of-type(1){}
3. have transitions and rotation on each .hamburger element : 2 make a cross, 1 disappears.

Comment: if you need examples or inspiration: https://codepen.io/designcouch/pen/Atyop